# air app reliable background execution

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air

i am creating an Air Application ( cross-platform but with focus on Android ) where GPS-locaton data is logged during a trip.
I use 
`NativeApplication.nativeApplication.executeInBackground = true;`
to make sure that logging continues, even when the user switches applications.

How reliable is that feature though?
Also can I force the application to stay in the foreground ( with user permission of course )?

thanks a bunch!

Comment: The mobile OSs usually are able to force things on apps especially when power and battery power is running low. Android especially will not let an app executing in background in low power condition. You cannot force an app to stay in foreground, no.

Comment: thanks a lot. need to find a workround then.